# round in javascript stuck me

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

hello I want to round an amount in javascript but unable to do and totally stuck. 
My scenario is, I have a `base` amount and `marukup %` on `base`. On the basis of these two I want to calculate `total amount`. I have calculated the amount but i want to round the result.
I have used following formula

`amount=base+((base/100)*markup`

This formula always give me result without decimal point. I want to get exact amount upto two decimal points. I have used `math.round` like this

`amount=math.round(base+((base/100)*markup).toFixed(2)`

but it always return result without decimal point. For example my base value is `121` and markup is `5%`. The `amount` should be `127.05` . But above formula always returns `127`. Any guidelines?

Comment: Don't know what you are doing, but `121+((121/100)*5)` gives me `127.05`. `Math.round` always [rounds to the nearest integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round), which, as far as I understood, you don't want.

Comment: @Flex Kling Thanks but I want to round the answer upto 2 decimals.. How can I do that?

Comment: All you ever wanted to know about rounding in javascript and formatting as money: http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/js-round.htm#RiJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `toFixed(n)` function rounds the Number to *n* decimals, there is no need to use `Math.round` at all. Try:

```
total = function (base, markup) { return (base + (base * markup / 100)); }; 
amount = total(121,5).toFixed(2);
```

Note that `amount` will be `typeof String` and not `Number`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure math.round returns an integer. Even if you round it then, it'll just be 127.00 anyway.

Here's the correct solution(but it isn't easy):
*Do not use non-integer values for money!*
It doesn't work.

Use an integer in cents.
That is, instead of 127, keep 12700 in your app.
That way all roundings should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:
    amout = (Math.round((base*(1+markup))*100)/100).toFixed(2)

By the way, i was using markup as 5/100...

Answer (score 0):

Sound like a integer division problem to me. I'd guess that javascript is seeing the 100 as an int.

Try this:

```
amount=(base+((base/100.toFixed(2))*markup).toFixed(2)
```